# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest only works with inspector open (Access-Control-Allow-Origin error)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to load an image from Amazon S3 using the JavaScript XMLHttpRequest() function.

```
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.onload = function (e) {
           if (e.target.status >= 300) {
             _this3.onImageError.call(_this3, _constants.ERRORS.IMAGE_FAILED_TO_LOAD);
             return;
           }
           _this3.loadFile(e.target.response);
         };
         xhr.open('GET', imageSrc);
         xhr.responseType = 'blob';
         xhr.send();`
```

My S3 bucket is properly configured for CORS (99% sure). Here's the rule I'm using, I plan on making the Origin more specific one this works:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

I've also tried the following rule (with identical results) as I really only care about GET requests at the moment:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

In Chrome, when attempting to load the image I get a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. If I first open the Inspector then attempt to load the image I get expected behavior with no error.

I've attempted to catch the request with Wireshark, since trying to monitor the bug with Inspector causes it to resolve itself, but have been unsuccessful.

The code I am trying to implement is here https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit .

The bug I am experiencing was mentioned in that repository here https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/issues/118 but nothing in the thread resolved my issue.

Curious if anyone has ever run into this wonky Inspector behavior before. Let me know if I can provide any more details/screenshots/what have you.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you using an Ajax request to load an image? My not just set the source?

Comment: It's platform code I didn't write so I can't really answer you fully. Ajax is being used to get a remote image here, like I mentioned it all works completely fine when Chrome's inspector is open so I can only assume the code is largely correct. I suppose I can try find an alternative method but that requires reworking a lot of code, I was hoping this was a simple config bug or that someone else knew some Chrome trick I didn't

Comment: @Alex I know it's an old one but did you ever figure out? Having the same issue and it is puzzling...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same behavior today.

For me, the problem was that on the same web page, the image is first downloaded to display in an img tag. Then, next to the `img` tag there is a download button, which uses fetch to download the image data, create an object url and force the browser to download the image an a tag with a download attribute (to be able to set a custom file name).

I had set up `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin` correctly on the s3 bucket where the image was stored, and things work correctly in Firefox, so I was surprised to see it failing randomly in Chrome, and not with the Web inspector open, as you say.

It turns out that when fetching the image with that URL, in Chrome you hit a cached version of the response from when the image was loaded in the `img` tag, and this response does not include the required `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin` header.

Adding `{cache: 'no-store'}` to the fetch request ensures that the cache is not hit, and that you get a fresh Response with the appropriate headers that is then not blocked.